# jplayer not working on mozilla and opera

Tags: javascript, jquery

jplayer is not working on mozilla and opera. Is there any chance to fix that? When I press play button, nothing happens, but on chrome, ie and Safari it works just great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox and Opera do not have native mp3 support;  but chrome, safari and internet explorer support mp3 natively.(i assume you are using newer versions).

Therefore, if the type of the file you are trying to play is mp3, you need to set the right path for **Jplayer.swf** for the player to work on firefox/opera.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, remove the `/`
ex :

```
swfPath:"js"
```

Comment: This does not add on to what previous people have said.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

opera and ff don't play mp3 in html50, but they play ogg. In order to play them, there isJplayer.swf file in js folder. You should write swfPath: "write the track of Jplayer.swf"...

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong but jplayer is working for me in firefox, i am using v 8.0.1. this is my code

```
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {},
    swfPath: "",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });

  $(".jp-play").live("click",function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
  });

  // I am applying mp3 file path dynamic by using below function  
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3 : "http://"+sound });
```

For more details check this post
http://www.amitpatil.me/ipad-online-dictionary-with-jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that it is important to define where is Jplayer.swf.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "/js" /*in this case your file is at /js/Jplayer.swf*/,
        supplied: "mp3"
        });
});
```